# %USERPROFILE% variable not working

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

If I try to create files in the command prompt using the commands

```
mkdir C:\Users\Tristan\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery
mkdir C:\Users\Tristan\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\mods
```

my computer will create the files without problems.

However, if I use the commands

```
mkdir C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery
mkdir C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\mods
```

the command prompt responds with

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 34):

The `%UserProfile%` variable is a special system-wide environment variable that is complete in and of itself. 
It contains `%SystemDrive%\Users\{username}`

See this fantastic table that [highlights the differences between variables in windows XP (NT5) and Windows Vista/7/8 (NT6)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_values).

Try

```
mkdir %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\mods
```

Its value is the location of the current user's profile directory, in which is found that user's HKEY_CURRENT_USER (HKCU) registry hive (NTUSER).

Answer (score 17):

I assume you mixed up the variables `%USERPROFILE%` and `%USERNAME%`.

By default, `%USERPROFILE%` and `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` point to the same location. Since this is not guaranteed to be true, using `%USERPROFILE%` is a more reliable approach.

In general, when debugging a command like

```
mkdir C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery
```

your first step should be to prepend `echo`.

The command

```
echo mkdir C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery
```

would have shown you the following:

```
mkdir C:\Users\C:\Users\Tristan\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery
```

which is clearly not what you want.

You can also query the value of `%USERPROFILE%` by executing

```
set USERPROFILE
```

To see all currently defined environment variables, execute

```
set
```

Answer (score 10):

It actually appears the OP is looking not just for C:\Users\Someone but that user's AppData\Roaming folder. So, the quickest path there is to use

```
%APPDATA%
```

In the OP's example, he would use

```
mkdir %APPDATA%\modinstaller\recovery
mkdir %APPDATA%\modinstaller\mods
```

Answer (score 2):

in PowerShell do not use

```
mkdir C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery
```

use this:

```
mkdir $home\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery
```

Comment: Thanks! Can anyone provide any background resources about this? I'm trying to understand why PowerShell would do this. When I run `code %USERPROFILE` the VSCode will open to my home directory... what gives?

Answer (score -2):

The %USERPROFILE% variable usually includes the C:\Users\AccountName so the correct usage would be

mkdir %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\modinstaller\recovery

Comment: This was already explained in both existing answers. If you like them, try to gain some reputation and [upvote them when you have 15 rep](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.