# How to generically refer to the AppData folder on the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, user-profiles, appdata

The original User's Profile directory lives in a directory like `C:\Users\username\AppData`.

How can I refer to the current user's profile directory when using the Windows command line?

By searching I found out about `%UserProfile%` that perhaps refer to the current username, but it does not really work. When I tried using it, I received the error *"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"*.

Comment: In what context do you get the error? `CD %USERPROFILE%` works as expected, as does `CD %LOCALAPPDATA%` and `CD %APPDATA%`

Comment: Wjen I used C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData

Comment: Ah. That would be the issue then.
C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData would expand to "C:\Users\C:\Users\Super\AppData"! "cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData" works as expected.

Comment: Thanks carveone...hope will be answering my needs further

Answer (score 15):

Here are some of the common system path variables on windows, but check here for a [complete reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows):

```
| Variable       | Default Value                                                                |
|----------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| %SystemDrive%  | C:                                                                           |
| %ProgramFiles% | C:\Program Files                                                             |
| %AppData%      | C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming                                          |
| %LocalAppData% | C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local                                            |
| %UserProfile%  | C:\Users\{username}                                                          |
| %UserName%     | {username}                                                                   |
| %COMPUTERNAME% | {computername}                                                               |
| %PATH%         | C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;{plus program paths} |
```

These should automatically be expanded when using the windows cmd prompt (or [bash / powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157368/1366033)):

```
cd %UserProfile%
```

Your specific issue here seems to be using `UserProfile` instead of `UserName`. Either use `cd %UserProfile%` or `cd C:\Users\%UserName%`

**Further Reading**:

- [`%USERPROFILE%` variable not working](https://superuser.com/q/571974/180163)
- [SS64 - Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [MS Docs - Recognized Environment Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables)

Comment: Good answer! I learned.

Comment: *Hint:* You can use `ECHO %variable%` to print its content in the console, e.g. `ECHO %UserProfile%` or you can use `SET variable` without assignment, which will also print it , e.g. `SET UserProfile`. And just typing `SET` prints *all* environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

Run a command shell (start/Run, then "cmd") and type "set". This will list all the environmental variables available. Having said that, USERPROFILE is perfectly valid. There's also APPDATA and LOCALAPPDATA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in PowerShell you could plug into a Win API.

List of possible names are:

```
[Environment+SpecialFolder].GetEnumNames()
```

You extract values by:

```
> [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Windows)
C:\WINDOWS
> [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::CommonPrograms)
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
> [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::CommonVideos)
C:\Users\Public\Videos
> [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::MyPictures)
C:\Users\user\Pictures
```